# WARN BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: No more replicas available for rdd

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm seeing the following type of messages when caching large dataframes in pyspark with YARN:-

```
WARN BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: No more replicas available for rdd_23_62 !
```

What exactly does this message mean?

Is it causing the subsequent `Container killed on request. Exit code is 143` error?

Comment: Maybe the following thread can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50420874/are-failed-spark-executors-a-cause-for-concern

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The container killed message is pretty common. It basically means 'something did not go as planned so Spark gave up'.

Though I could not find any great references for the exact error, my understanding is as follows:

When spark has to work on data, it replicates this across nodes. (Primarily in memory, though depending on the situation/settings it might choose to spill to disk).

The message itself seems to be pretty clear: It was trying to work on data, and did not find any replica available to do so.

What I do not know is the root cause.

1. It may be that somehow taking in the data failed
2. Alternately perhaps it was succesfull in creating a replica but this cannot be accessed now

In the latter case, I could think of two main reasons:

- A valid replica exists but accessing it fails (e.g. some kind of networking issue)
- Though it was valid once, there is no valid replica now. Perhaps it got corrupted or kicked out (e.g. by another application?)

I know this leaves some possibilities open, but hopefully this helps in coming to the root cause.